# How to increment text on cart icon which is present in Bottom Navigation bar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Help me out, how to do the following for bottom navigation icon

Comment: Just create a layout with the shopping cart icon with the circle and a `TextView` in it that you can update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  below code to show badge count in bottom navigation menu item.

```
        navViewBottom.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.shoppingCartFragment).number = value
```

Here, shoppingCartFragment is menu item id. You need to use material design theme to achieve this.